# App crashes when rotating device after adding option to change GridView Templates

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I Have an app that has a GridView bound to sampledata. I have a button that can switch layouts (list, to grid) of the GridView. It works fine, but the minute I rotate the phone after changing the datatemplate the app crashes. I get this in the App.g.i.cs file:

```
DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
```

I've narrowed it down to this bit of code being the problem:

```
FontIcon fi = new FontIcon(); 
fi.Glyph = "\uE80A"; 
ViewItems.Icon = fi; 
ViewItemsBottom.Icon = fi;
```

I don't know why. My appbarbutton has a custom glyph as the icon and this is where I change that. When I rotate the phone after changing this using the above code the app crashes. If I comment out this part of the code, no crash. Anyone know how to get around this?

---

The way I am changing templates is I have two DataTemplates defined in the Page resources:

```
<Page.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="WideTile" x:Name="WideTile">
        <StackPanel Width="300" Height="80" Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal"
                               Background="{ThemeResource MainBackgroundColor}" 
                               BorderBrush="#11000000"
                               BorderThickness="0,0,2,2"
                               Padding="10">
            <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="40" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <BitmapIcon Width="40" Height="40" 
                                        UriSource="Assets/recipeicon.png" Foreground="{Binding IconColor}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid Width="200" Height="80" Margin="20,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding RecipeName}" 
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       FontSize="16"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SquareTile" x:Name="SquareTile">
        <StackPanel Width="150" Height="150" Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical"
                               Background="{ThemeResource MainBackgroundColor}" 
                               BorderBrush="#11000000"
                               BorderThickness="0,0,2,2"
                               Padding="10">
            <StackPanel Margin="0,30,0,0" Width="130" Height="110" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <BitmapIcon Width="50" Height="50" 
                                        UriSource="Assets/recipeicon.png" Foreground="{Binding IconColor}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid Width="150" Height="20" Margin="0,-30,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding RecipeName}" 
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       FontSize="12"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

and I have  button that calls this code to make the change:

```
private void ViewItems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (gridViewStyle == "0")
        {
            gridViewStyle = "1";
        } else if (gridViewStyle == "1")
        {
            gridViewStyle = "0";
        }

        setGridViewLayout();
        localSettings.Values["gridViewStyle"] = gridViewStyle;
    }


    private void setGridViewLayout()
    {
        if (gridViewStyle == "0")
        {
            DataTemplate tmpl;
            tmpl = WideTile;
            recipeGridView.ItemTemplate = tmpl;

            FontIcon fi = new FontIcon();
            fi.Glyph =  "\uE80A";

            ViewItems.Icon = fi;
            ViewItems.Label = "Square";
            ViewItemsBottom.Icon = fi;
            ViewItemsBottom.Label = "Square";
        }
        else if (gridViewStyle == "1")
        {
            DataTemplate tmpl; 
            tmpl = SquareTile;
            recipeGridView.ItemTemplate = tmpl;

            FontIcon fi = new FontIcon();
            fi.Glyph = "\uE292";

            ViewItems.Icon = fi;
            ViewItems.Label = "Wide";
            ViewItemsBottom.Icon = fi;
            ViewItemsBottom.Label = "Wide";
        }
    }
```

Most of that code is just to change the appbar icon glyphs and text depending on what view they are currently in, but the jist of it is I am doing this to change the datatemplate:

```
DataTemplate tmpl;
tmpl = WideTile;
recipeGridView.ItemTemplate = tmpl;
```

If I load the app and DONT change the gridview, when I rotate the phone there is no crashing. The MINUTE I have manually assigned the datatemplate, the phone crashes when I rotate it.

If you are curious, this is my visual state manager XAML that is called when I rotate the phone:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>

            <!-- Wider than 600px -->
            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="TheCommandBar.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Target="TheCommandBarBottom.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <!-- Narrower than 600px -->
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="TheCommandBar.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter Target="TheCommandBarBottom.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: I managed to work around it by just having an extra appbarbutton that I hide/show depending on what view the user has selected. but I would still like to know why I cant directly modify the glyph of an appbarbutton and then rotate the phone. If anyone knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, you just can't reuse the same FontIcon twice.

This code works just fine:

```
FontIcon fi = new FontIcon();
FontIcon fi2 = new FontIcon();

fi.Glyph = "\uE80A";
fi2.Glyph = "\uE80A";

ViewItems.Icon = fi;
ViewItemsBottom.Icon = fi2;
```